# How singleton pattern is useful for me in this scenario?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am supposed to write a WCF service which retrieves the customer information from the AppServer (which connects database) and expose it to the ATM clients. We will be installing the service and hosted in IIS in one server. There will be multiple clients over the network and it will be accessing the service hosted in IIS.

My doubt is how singleton instance will handle multiple requests with one instance? I am still could not understand the use of singleton. Its definition says only one instance will be created for the service. But how it handles the multiple requests? or Should I create the object for every request?

Below is my code. (There may be error in code but I just want to understand the use of singleton)

***Class in Appserver***

```
class Customer
{
    public Dataset Getcustdetails(int customerid)

    {   


    }
}
```

***class in WebService***

```
class Singleton
{
    Dataset custds;

    private static Singleton instance = null;
        private static readonly object padlock = new object();

      Singleton()
            {
       }

        public static Singleton Instance
    {
           get
          {
           lock (padlock)
           {
                if (instance == null)
                 {
                 instance = new Singleton();
                  }
                 return instance;
           }
         }
           }


    public bool GetCustomerdetails(int customerid, out DataSet customerDS)

       {    
         Customer objcust = new Customer();             //will the objcust created everytime for every request? or the customer class should also be singleton?
         custds = objcust.Getcustdetails(customerid);               //custds dataset should be declared inside this method or inside the class?
         customerDS = custds ;
         return true;

       }

}
```

***Class in Client***

```
namespace Client1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dataset ds ;
        Singleton SingletonObject = Singleton.Instance();
           bool returnval= SingletonObject.GetCustomerdetails(1234,ds);

        }
    }

}

//**Acessing at the same time from a different client for same customer**/

namespace Client2
{
    class Program2
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dataset ds ;
        Singleton SingletonObject = Singleton.Instance();
           bool returnval= SingletonObject.GetCustomerdetails(1234,ds);

        }
    }
}

namespace Client3
{
    class Program3
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dataset ds ;
        Singleton SingletonObject = Singleton.Instance();
           bool returnval= SingletonObject.GetCustomerdetails(5678,ds);

        }
    }
}
```

My doubts in the above code

will the objcust created everytime for every request? or the customer class should also be singleton?
custds dataset should be declared inside this method or inside the class?

Comment: If you don't understand the pattern, you shouldn't be using it.  Learn the pattern first, then you will be in a better position to use it properly when the occasion arises.

Comment: WCF has built in mechanism for Singleton, doesn't it?

Comment: You have a singleton in your webservice, yet you are using that same singleton from your client code? Also where is the WCF part? Is your singleton actually just an instance for your client code that is accessing the WCF service underneath?

Comment: Your code sample does not use WCF. You are consuming the singleton in-process, not across a service boundary. For in-process calls you cannot use WCF.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly that

if class `Singleton` is an implementation of the service that this class should be mark attribute `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]`.

[Singleton service](http://wcftutorial.net/singleton-service.aspx)

In this case for each client will create one instance of service.
Otherwise for each client will create own instance of service.